# Pandas Conditional Replace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', np.nan], 
                   'COL2' : ['A','A']})
df

    COL1    COL2
0   A       A
1   NaN     A
```

How might I replace the second cell in COL2 with "NaN" (that is, make it null) if the corresponding cell under COL1 is null ("NaN")?

Desired Result:

```
    COL1    COL2
0   A       A
1   NaN     NaN
```

Note: I'm looking for a systematic solution that will work across n rows of COL1 and COL2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by indexing into the data frame where `COL1` is nan:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', np.nan]*100000, 
                   'COL2' : ['A','A']*100000})

df.loc[df.COL1.isnull(), 'COL2'] = np.nan
```

I used a larger dataframe so that we can compare timings:

```
%timeit df.loc[df.COL1.isnull(), 'COL2'] = np.nan
100 loops, best of 3: 5.36 ms per loop
```

Compared to the previous solution which is also a good solution:

```
%timeit df['COL2'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['COL1']), np.nan, df['COL2'])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
df['COL2'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['COL1']), np.nan, df['COL2'])
```

Is there a preferable way?